# SQL query across 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having problems with figuring out how to do SQL query in next situaion.

I have 3 tables as follows:

TABLE.BOOKS

```
book_id |   title           |   author          |   language
-------------------------------------------------------------
1       |   Title one       |   Author, One     |   english  
2       |   Another title   |   Second, Name    |   french
```

TABLE.PUBLISHERS

```
publ_id |   publisher       |   city    
---------------------------------------------
1       |   Company one     |   Munich  
2       |   Books ltd       |   London  
41      |   WEpublish co    |   Paris
```

TABLE.BOOK_PUBLISHER

```
book_id |   publ_id
---------------------
1       |   2  
2       |   41
```

From tables above I'd like to write a query that would return me data from the books table with publisher data added, something like this:

```
['Title one', 'Author, One', 'english', 'Books ltd', 'London']  
['Another title', 'Second, Name', 'french', 'WEpublish co', 'Paris']
```

Can anyone advise me, how such SQL query should look like? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you should read about `JOIN`! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: I've only did JOINS between 2 tables so far, but never had a case as above. If atleast you could advise me what type of JOIN would be needed I'd Google it :)

Comment: Simply start with a two table join. When it works, add another join!

Comment: Go through this. www.geeksforgeeks.org/joining-three-tables-sql/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic `JOIN` from `books` to `publishers` via `book_publisher`:

```
SELECT b.title, b.author, b.language, p.publisher, p.city
FROM books b
JOIN book_publisher bp ON bp.book_id = b.book_id
JOIN publishers p ON p.publ_id = bp.publ_id
```

Output:

```
title           author          language    publisher       city
Title one       Author, One     english     Books ltd       London
Another title   Second, Name    french      WEpublish co    Paris
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hW3oCHKCbcmv3FkHUCUy17/0)

Answer (score 1):

You have to `JOIN` the three tables to get the result.

```
select title,author,language,publisher,city
from BOOKS
join BOOK_PUBLISHER on BOOK_PUBLISHER.book_id = BOOKS.book_id
join PUBLISHERS on PUBLISHERS.publ_id = BOOK_PUBLISHER.publ_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by the following query:

```
select b.title,b.author,b.language,p.publisher,p.city from Table1 b join Table3 pb on pb.book_id=b.book_id join Table2 p ON p.publ_id = pb.publ_id
```